# ISO date argument for Drupal Views

Tags: date

I am trying to figure out an ISO formatted date which will say to Drupal, "grab the first weeks of events for the month"

Something like this:

YYYY-MM-DD--P3M - where I am interpreting this as saying get the YEAR-MONTH-DAY for a three month period?

I'm not quite sure how to read that - but my point that I need to reach is the format to grab the first week of a month - either a specific month, (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD-- P1W) or something like (11-- 1W).

Let me know if I need to provide additional information - I'm not sure how to precisely speak about the concepts I'm requesting.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the first week of a month by specifying the month in question, with the first day of that month, and adding P1W to it.

Like so:

```
2014-1-1--P1W
```

Would grab the first week of 2014.

In actuality, I figured out that I needed the given week for a given day, which is done by providing the day, for example today:

```
2013-11-26--P1W
```

Which will give you the current week.